# Why is AJAX pager in Views not recording the history

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a listing of news, used with [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) in Drupal 7. I have activated Use Ajax in advanced section. So now the pager loads the content smoothly, without loading other page. That is nice, but the pager is not recording the history of the browser, so when I hit several pages of the same listing, it loads all the content perfectly but when I hit the **Back button** of the browser, instead of going to the last page clicked on the listing, goes to a previously visited site, even a different website, depending on my browser history. This happens, aparently, because there seems to be no built-in mechanism to record website history or at least change the toolbar address with "#" so it can have a behaviour similar to what be expected. Is there some way of circumventing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used but you can take a look

[Statehandler](https://www.drupal.org/project/statehandler) module and [History.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/history_js) module

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a look. I am very surprised that it is not standard behaviour. This one and the "click enter twice" issue of the Autocomplete input fields do put Drupal sites behaviour to the final user as if the pages had been made 5-10 years ago!

Comment: @Cesar did you get any success in integrating Ajax page with history.js?